# Can't use $("#item_id").text as $.get callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I have that code to get some data from cgi-script. It works perfectly.

```
$.get('cgi/remote_user', function(data){
  $('#user_id').text(data);
});
```

But if I try to set `$('#user_id').text` as callback function, it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`:

```
$.get('cgi/remote_user', $('#user_id').text);
```

Any idea why it is? `$('#user_id').text` is the same function as `function(data) {}`..

I suspect it could be invalid context of invocation, I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you get the reference to the `text` function, it's no longer attached to the object. It will called in the global context (window) instead of the context of the object.

You can use the `proxy` method to bind the function to the context:

```
var user = $('#user_id');
$.get('cgi/remote_user', $.proxy(user.text), user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('cgi/remote_user', $('#user_id').text);
```

is like writing:

```
var tmp = $('#user_id').text;
$.get('cgi/remote_user', tmp);
```

which is qeuivalent to

```
$.get('cgi/remote_user', $.fn.text);
```

without `$('#user_id')` being `this`.

what you want is

```
$.get('cgi/remote_user', $.fn.text.bind($('#user_id')));
```

Comment: The `bind` method is not supported in IE 8 and earlier, so it's better to use the `$.proxy` method.